# Was Haru actually trying to kill Yamaken?

Tags: tonari-no-kaibutsu-kun

In Episode 10 of *Tonari no Kaibatsu-kun*, after Yamaken asked Haru "What if Mizutani-san says that she likes me more?", Haru thought for a second and then slowly reached out to Yamaken. However, before he can do whatever he was thinking, Mizutani asked what he was up to and he snapped out of his thoughts.

Was Haru actually planning to kill Yamaken by pushing him off the stairs?